# How to bind multiple onChange callback for different inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am making a different form component using ant design and trying to bind several different inputs

Here is the code :

```
this.state = {
    title: '',
    product: '',
    options: 0,
    price: 0,
}

onTitleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        title: e.target.value
    })
}

onProductChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        product: e.target.value
    })
}

onHandleChange = value => {
    this.setState({
        priceOption: value
    })
}

onNumberChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        price: e.target.value
    })
}


<FormItemRow>
<Col span={24} style={colStyle}>
    <FormItem label={'title'} colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
        {getFieldDecorator('title', {
            rules: [
                { required: true, message: 'title is required' },
            ],
        })(<Input onChange={this.onTitleChange}/>)}
    </FormItem>
</Col>
</FormItemRow>

<FormItemRow>
<Col span={24} style={colStyle}>
    <FormItem label={'product-number'} colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
        {getFieldDecorator('product-number', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'product-number is required' }],
        })(<Input onChange={this.onProductChange}/>)}
    </FormItem>
</Col>
</FormItemRow>

<FormItemRow>
<Col span={12} style={colStyle}>
    <FormItem label={'options'} colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
        {getFieldDecorator('options', {
            rules: [
                { required: true, message: 'options is required' },
            ],
        })(<Select onChange={this.onHandleChange}>{this.handWashOptions(this.props.handWashOptions)}</Select>)}
    </FormItem>
</Col>
<Col span={12} style={colStyle}>
    <FormItem label={'price'} colon={false} style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
        {getFieldDecorator('price', {
            rules: [
                { required: true, message: 'price is required' },
            ],
        })(<Input type="number" onChange={this.onNumberChange}/>)}
    </FormItem>
</Col>
</FormItemRow>
```

title and product using just **Input** component.

option is using **Select** component.

and price is using **Input type number** component.

I think it is very inefficient using different onChange callback on each input component.

Is there any way I can bind one onChange callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a generic function handleChange, pass the name and value which are to be updated

```
 handleChange(name,value){
   this.setState({[name]: value})
 }
```

and pass value to handle change like this

```
<Input onChange={(name,value)=>this.onTitleChange(name,value)}/>
```

You can use `e.target.value` to get `value` from target, also if you need to have different logic for some particular element then you can simply add a exception in `handleChange`

Answer (score -1):

```
    this.state = {
        fields:{
            each:
            field:
            you:
            have:
          }
      }




    handleChange = (event) => {
                const { value, type, name } = event.currentTarget
                console.log(type, value, name);
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    fields: {
                        ...prevState.fields,
                        [name]: type === 'number' ? parseInt(value, 10) : value
                    }
                }));
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated in [Handling Multiple Inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs),

> **add a name attribute to each element** and let the handler function choose what to do based on the value of **event.target.name**.

So you can have:

```
onChange = event => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({
       [name]: event.target.value
    })
}

// Add `name` attribute used for event.target.name
<Select onChange={this.onChange} name="wash">...</Select>
<Input type="number" onChange={this.onChange} name="number"/>
<Input onChange={this.onChange} name="product" />
```